# Shallow water equations in differential form and cylindrical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, hyperbolic-equations, cylindrical-coordinates

I am ignoring bed height or any other extra terms. The version of SWE when written in cartesian is:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
h  \\
hu  \\
hv  \\
\end{pmatrix}_t  + 
\begin{pmatrix}
hu  \\
hu^2 + \frac{g}{2} h^2  \\
huv  \\
\end{pmatrix}_x  +\begin{pmatrix}
hv  \\
huv \\
hv^2 + \frac{g}{2} h^2   \\
\end{pmatrix}_y = 0
$

First what is it in differential form? I think it is:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h + \nabla \cdot (hv) = 0 \quad 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}h + \nabla \cdot (hvv) = - \nabla \frac{h^2}{2} g  $
The pressure term at the end is what I'm really uncertain about. I think it must be a gradient as it comes from the pressure gradient term and it seems to fit but I couldn't derive it from Euler. **What is it supposed to be?**

Finally to write SWE in cylindrical coordinates, if I had the correct differential form can I just use the del in cylindrical coordinates formulas and $v = (u_r, u_\theta)$ and plug these in to get it? **And can I expect it to be harder to solve in cylindrical as I seem to get forcing terms?**

Comment: Cross posted on physics: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/497135/25301

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes since I was unsure which to post it in and think people on both forums could have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mass continuity equation.* The first line of the system gives indeed the scalar conservation law
$$
\partial_t h + \mathrm{div} (h \boldsymbol{v}) = 0 .
$$
Using the vector calculus identity $\mathrm{div} (h \boldsymbol{v}) = h \,\mathrm{div}\, \boldsymbol{v} + \mathbf{grad}\, h\cdot \boldsymbol{v}$ and the definition of the material time derivative $D_t$, we have also $D_t h = -h \,\mathrm{div}\, \boldsymbol{v}$.

*Momentum equation.* The remaining lines give an equation on $h \boldsymbol v$. In the absence of fluid rotation and with a flat bottom surface, the conservation of momentum reads $D_t \boldsymbol{v} = -\mathbf{grad}(g h)$. After a bit of tensor calculus, one should arrive at
$$
 \partial_t (h \boldsymbol{v}) + \mathbf{div}(h \boldsymbol{v}\otimes \boldsymbol{v}) = -\mathbf{grad}(\tfrac12 gh^2) ,
$$
where $\otimes$ is the tensor product. Using the identity $\mathbf{grad}\psi = \mathbf{div}(\psi \boldsymbol{I})$ for the scalar field $\psi = \tfrac12 gh^2$ where $\boldsymbol{I}$ is the identity tensor, we can rewrite the above equation as a single conservation law.

Of course, it is possible to solve this system in [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) by setting
$x = r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$. With $\boldsymbol{u} = h\boldsymbol{v}$ and $\boldsymbol{T} = \frac1h \boldsymbol{u}\otimes \boldsymbol{u} + \frac12 gh^2\boldsymbol{I} = \boldsymbol{T}^\top$, the above equations of motion lead to the system
\begin{aligned}
\partial_t h + \partial_r u_{r} + \partial_\theta (\tfrac{1}{r} u_{\theta}) &= -\tfrac{1}{r} u_r \\
\partial_t u_r + \partial_r T_{rr} + \partial_\theta (\tfrac{1}{r} T_{r\theta}) &= -\tfrac{1}{r} (T_{rr} - T_{\theta\theta}) \\
\partial_t u_\theta + \partial_r T_{r\theta} + \partial_\theta (\tfrac{1}{r}T_{\theta\theta})  &= -\tfrac{2}{r}T_{r\theta}
\end{aligned}
which may be written
\begin{aligned}
\partial_t h + \partial_r (hv_{r}) + \tfrac{1}{r} \partial_\theta ( hv_{\theta}) &= -\tfrac{h}{r} v_r \\
\partial_t (hv_r) + \partial_r (h{v_r}^2 + \tfrac12 gh^2) + \tfrac{1}{r}\partial_\theta ( hv_rv_\theta) &= -\tfrac{h}{r} ({v_r}^2 - {v_\theta}^2) \\
\partial_t (hv_\theta) + \partial_r (hv_rv_\theta) + \tfrac{1}{r} \partial_\theta (h{v_\theta}^2 + \tfrac12 gh^2)  &= -\tfrac{2 h}{r}v_r v_\theta
\end{aligned}
You may have a look at (1) for examples with cylindrical symmetry, i.e. where $\boldsymbol v$ is along the radial direction and where the flow is independent on $\theta$. In that case, the previous system becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_t h + \partial_r u_r &= -\tfrac{1}{r} u_r \\
\partial_t u_r + \partial_r T_{rr} &= - \tfrac{1}{r h} {u_r}^2
\end{aligned}
$$
with $T_{rr} = \frac1h {u_r}^2 + \frac12 gh^2$. The speeds of sound of this $2\times 2$ hyperbolic system are $v_r \pm \sqrt{g h}$.

The previous case of cylindrical waves is pretty easy to solve numerically (cf. the mentioned article (1)), e.g. by using dedicated finite-volume methods. However, the full system in polar coordinates is not as easy to solve, mostly because of the $1/r$ factors in the flux derivatives w.r.t. $\theta$. These factors make this problem space dependent in a certain way.

---

(1) P. Glaister, "Shallow water flow with cylindrical symmetry", *J. Hydraul. Res.* **29**:2 (1991), 219-227. [doi:10.1080/00221689109499005](https://doi.org/10.1080/00221689109499005)

Comment: I got this yesterday: (I kept h and u seperate) They are slightly different, do you see anything obviously wrong in my answer or a mistake in yours? $
\begin{pmatrix}
h  \\
hu_r  \\
rhu_\theta  \\
\end{pmatrix}_t  + 
\begin{pmatrix}
hu_r  \\
hu_r^2 + \frac{g}{2} h^2  \\
rhu_ru_\theta  \\
\end{pmatrix}_r  +\begin{pmatrix}
hu_\theta  \\
hu_ru_\theta \\
rhu_\theta^2 + \frac{g}{2r} h^2   \\
\end{pmatrix}_\theta +\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{r}hu_r \\
\frac{1}{r}hu_r^2-2rhu_\theta^2 \\
3hu_ru_\theta  \\
\end{pmatrix}= 0
$

Comment: @Salamander Answer edited! They are indeed quite close, but you have some obvious mistakes. Indeed, in the first line, $(hu_r)_r$ is expressed in m/s while $(hu_θ)_θ$ is expressed in m²/s. You are missing the $1/r$ factors.